# Flutter: setear mi app por defecto para abrir archivos json en android

Tags: android, json, flutter

Estoy intentando establecer mi app para que sea aplicación por defecto para que cuando un usuario hace tap en un archivo abra la app y pueda leerlo.

Actualmente tengo la funcionalidad que es seleccionar el archivo json y compartir a mi app
y eso si me esta funcionando.

pubspec.yaml

```
environment:
 sdk: ">=3.1.3 <4.0.0"
dependencies:
receive_sharing_intent: ^1.4.5
```

He declaro esto en AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:exported="true" 
 android:launchMode="singleTask">
 <intent-filter>
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/json" />
            </intent-filter>
```

con esta configuración si logro asociar mi app para que se abra haciendo tap en archivos json.
Pero tengo 2 comportamientos.
Si el archivo json lo tengo en whatsapp.
usando el código que ya tenia recibo esto como argumento y no se como hacer para leer el archivo.

Usando el siguiente codigo

uso este codigo, uso a modo de prueba los dos.

```
 ReceiveSharingIntent.getTextStreamAsUri().listen((event) {
    print('gettext stream as uri $event');
  });

  ReceiveSharingIntent.getTextStream().listen((event) async {
    print('as string $event dddd');  
  });
```

Obtengo este resultado.

```
'content://com.whatsapp.provider.media/item/f49880e7-c89d-48c0-94dc-19a0c896b77e'
```

Pero no se como leerlo, aquí espero leer el archivo json.

Pero si abro otro otra app. ejm. telegram.
No logro recibir nada. la app no se entera que la app se abrió usando un archivo json.

Alguna alma caritativa que me da una luz de como solucionar se lo agradeceria,

Saludos